# Using python how to find elements in a list of lists based on a key that is an element of the inner list?

Tags: python

Suppose I have a list of lists or a list of tuples, whichever can solve my problem more efficiently. Eg:

```
student_tuples = [
    ('john', 'A', 15),
    ('jane', 'B', 12),
    ('dave', 'B', 10),
]
```

The task is to find an element in the main list based on a key that is any element of the inner list or tuple. Eg:

Using the list above:

```
find(student_tuples, 'A')
```

or

```
find(student_tuples, 15)
```

would both return

```
('john', 'A', 15)
```

I'm looking for an efficient method.

Comment: You should consider making a `Student` class and having your list of students contain instances of that class.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would use `filter()` or a list comprehension.

```
def find_listcomp(students, value):
    return [student for student in students if student[1] == value or student[2] == value]

def find_filter(students, value):
    return filter(lambda s: s[1] == value or s[2] == value, students)
```

Comment: You could improve this by changing the return value to: return [student for student in students if value in student].  Otherwise, it will only return a hit for the 2nd and 3rd values in the tuple.

Comment: @bigmattyh: That would return `('john'...)` if `value == 'john'`, which isn't what OP wants.

Comment: He said: "The task is to find an element in the main list based on a key that is **any element of the inner list or tuple**."

Comment: I will combine your second solution with the one @sverre has provided to get: `return filter(lambda s: value in s, students)`

Answer (score 10):

To find the first match only, you can use

```
def find(list_of_tuples, value):
    return next(x for x in list_of_tuples if value in x)
```

This will raise `StopIteration` if no matching record is found.  To raise a more appropriate exception, you can use

```
def find(list_of_tuples, value):
    try:
        return next(x for x in list_of_tuples if value in x)
    except StopIteration:
        raise ValueError("No matching record found")
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use python's list comprehensions to select and filter:

```
def find(tuples, term):
    return [tuple for tuple in tuples if term in tuple]
```

Comment: I like this one, but it has a typo: `if term in tuples` should be `if term in tuple`

Comment: as I have commented in the solution by @Daenyth, I will combine the two of yours. Both answers are good, I accepted the other because it came earlier.

Answer (score 0):

This function will return a list of the tuples contain your search term.  Here you go:

```
def find_in_tuples(tuples, term):
    matching_set = []
    for tuple in tuples:
        if term in tuple:
            matching_set.append(tuple)
    return matching_set

>>> find_in_tuples(student_tuples, 'A')
[('john', 'A', 15)]
>>> find_in_tuples(student_tuples, 'B')
[('jane', 'B', 12), ('dave', 'B', 10)]
```